# Error to validate ECDSA signature in pkcs7

Tags: java, c#, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, pkcs11interop

I have successfully generate pkcs7 signature ECDSAwithSHA256 using C# , but then i failed to verify signature using java

Here is sample class

```
public class TestVerify {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String Signature = "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";
    String SigDateTime = "14-10-2020 10:58:22";
    String certtype = "token";
    String TimestampToken = "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";
    String pdfhash = "faadTnFU4cOBsl+sW98ie7KInSbbw0HDbgFeOcsRCAQ=";
            
    CMSSignedData signedDataTSToken = null;
    TimeStampToken tstoken = null;
    byte[] sigDataBytes = null;
    Date sigDate = null;
    
    CMSSignerHelper cmsHelper = new CMSSignerHelper();
    CMSSignedData cmsData;
    
    try {
        
         sigDataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Signature);
        cmsData = new CMSSignedData(sigDataBytes);
        
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        sigDate = formatter.parse(SigDateTime);
        
        byte[] tsTokenDataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(TimestampToken);
        signedDataTSToken = new CMSSignedData(tsTokenDataBytes);
        tstoken = new TimeStampToken(signedDataTSToken);
        
         verifyCMSSignatureMTID(sigDataBytes, sigDate, TimestampToken, pdfhash);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
    }
}

public static void verifyCMSSignatureMTID(byte[] signature, Date signing_date, String encodedTimestampToken, String PdfHash) throws OperatorCreationException, CMSException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, ParseException, TSPException, IOException, Exception {
    
    String fName="[verifyCMSSignatureMTID] ";
    VSInfo vsi=new VSInfo();        
    String initErr="CMS";
    
    //******************** VERIFY SGNATURE VS SIGNER PUBLICKEY **********************
    // Verify signature 
    byte[] HashByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(PdfHash);
    CMSProcessableByteArray processable = new CMSProcessableByteArray(HashByte);
    CMSSignedData cmsData = new CMSSignedData(signature);
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder_v=null;
    
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    
    try {

       Store store = cmsData.getCertificates();
       ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signature);
       CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(processable, stream);
       SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos();
       Collection c_v = signers.getSigners();
       Iterator it_v = c_v.iterator();
       while (it_v.hasNext()) {
           SignerInformation signer_v = (SignerInformation) it_v.next(); 
           Collection certCollection_v = store.getMatches(signer_v.getSID()); 
           Iterator certIt_v = certCollection_v.iterator();
           certHolder_v = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt_v.next();
           X509Certificate certFromSignedData_v = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certHolder_v);

           if (signer_v.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build(certFromSignedData_v))) {
               System.out.println(fName + "Signature verified");
           } else {
               System.out.println(fName + "Error CMS200 Signature is invalid");
               System.out.println(initErr+"200");
               System.out.println("Signature is invalid");
               return;
           }
           
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println(fName + "Error CMS200 Signature is invalid : " + e);
       System.out.println("200");
       System.out.println("Signature is invalid");
       return;
    }
        
    System.out.println("000");
    System.out.println("Signature is valid");
    return;
}
```

}

**Error**

> org.bouncycastle.operator.RuntimeOperatorException: exception
> obtaining signature: error decoding signature bytes.

However, i have succesfully verify RSAwithSHA256 signature using this method. Can someone help me on this and kindly explain what that error is about. The signature length for those signature is 256byte for RSA and 64byte for ECDSA . is it correct?

Comment: for ECDSA, did the result return signature is invalid?

Comment: yes, it return invalid .. you can try the sample code above

Comment: can you post your jar library?